# passport User is not a function

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mean

I keep getting the same error "User is not a function" when I call my API method.

Has anybody got an ideas why this might be.

Api method:

```js
//need to export the api methods.
var User = require('../models/user');
var passport = require('passport');

module.exports.create = function(req, res) {
  //TODO: error checking.
  var user = new User();
  console.log(req);
  user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
  user.secondName = req.body.secondName;
  user.email = req.body.email;

  user.setPassword(req.body.password);

  user.save(function(err) {
    res.status(200);
  });
};
```

user model:

```html
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');

var userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});

userSchema.methods.setPassword = function(password){
};

userSchema.methods.validPassword = function(password) {
};

mongoose.model('User', userSchema);
```

Let me know if I need to enter any more files.

Thanks

Comment: you don't appear to be exporting your User model

Comment: mongoose.export.model('User', userSchema) ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to export the mongoose model you created at the end of the User Model file.  Something like

`module.exports = mongoose.model('User', userSchema);`